# Linear separability

Tags: svm

What algorithm should be used to find the plane for a linearly separable dataset? I know that this is a quadratic programming problem, but I can’t find a suitable algorithm, could you please help?

**Problem:**

X = $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ - dataset, $Y = \{y_1, ..., y_n\}$ - classes. $y_i \in \{1, -1\}, x_i \in \mathbb{R^n}$. You should find vector $(a_1, ..., a_n, b) $ : $\forall i = \overline{1,n} \ sign((a_i, x_i) + b) = y_i$.

Comment: you tagged it with "svm," though!

Comment: I might be missing something! But why wouldn't you use the logistic regression? Its definition is to separate linearly separable data points.

Comment: The two most popular methods would be logistic regression (followed by appropriate thresholding of the predicted probabilities) and support vector machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [linear discriminate analysis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis&ved=2ahUKEwio9buZt7XjAhXRrJ4KHXtnAWwQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2uVsrInD-1FNR1Xq6BxKW0&cshid=1563142444995)
, a method used in statistics, pattern recognition and machine learning to find a linear combination of features that characterizes or separates two or more classes of objects or events. The resulting combination may be used as a linear classifier.